# How to call a Google Cloud Function from Google Cloud Scheduler when ingressSettings = ALLOW_INTERNAL_ONLY?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have, in the same project, one HTTP Cloud Function and a Cloud Scheduler, that sends a POST request to this function.
I want to allow only requests from within the project to call the Function. However, when I set Ingress Settings to "Allow internal traffic only", the Cloud Scheduler gets "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Here is the error log (edited)

```
httpRequest: {
  status: 403   
 }
 insertId: "insert_id"  

jsonPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"   
  jobName: "projects/project_name/locations/location/jobs/cloud_scheduler_job"   
  status: "PERMISSION_DENIED"   
  targetType: "HTTP"   
  url: "https://location-project_name.cloudfunctions.net/cloud_function_name"   
 }
 logName: "projects/project_name/logs/cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-02-20T13:15:43.134508712Z"  

resource: {

labels: {
   job_id: "cloud_scheduler_name"    
   location: "location"    
   project_id: "project_id"    
  }
  type: "cloud_scheduler_job"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 timestamp: "2020-02-20T13:15:43.134508712Z"  
}
```

[Link to UI options for ingressSettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0yXD.png)

Comment: I recreated what you described.  My best guess is that even though the Cloud Scheduler definition is created in the same project, it isn't considered a "resource" that connects with the Cloud Function from within the same project.

Comment: I sent your use case to Google PM. Interesting usage of Scheduler and internal functions!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you use the option "Allow internal traffic only" you need to use some kind of authentication within your Cloud Functions(to avoid this you can use the option "Allow all traffic").

please check the third comment provided in the link: https://serverfault.com/questions/1000987/trigger-google-cloud-functions-from-google-cloud-scheduler-with-private-network

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks! I first created a service account and set iam-policy to allow only invocations for that service account. Then I followed the steps described here https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth to use this service account in Cloud Scheduler request

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

> To use Cloud Scheduler your Cloud project must contain an App Engine
>   app that is located in one of the supported regions. If your project
>   does not have an App Engine app, you must create one.

[Cloud Scheduler overview](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs)

Therefore find the location of your app engine application by running:

```
gcloud app describe
#check for the locationId: europe-west2
```

Then make sure that you deploy your cloud function with Ingress Settings to "Allow internal traffic only" to the same location as your app engine application.

I deployed a cloud function in the same region as my app engine application and everything worked as expected.

Comment: This does not work for me. I have everything deployed to `us-central1`, but it still fails with `PERMISSION_DENIED` when calling from Cloud Scheduler with Ingress setting to internal traffic only.